# Is there a limit to the number of Union calls with Linq2Sql?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, limit, union

When using the Union method of Linq, with Entity Framework, is there an upper limit to the number of times it can be used on the same `IQueryable`?

Consider this snippet, obviously a bit contrived:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople(IEnumerable<PersonDto> candidates)
{
    var successful = this.peopleRepository.All().Where(p => false);

    foreach(var candidate in candidates)
    {
        if (candidate.IsSuccessful())
        {
            var successfulCandidate = this.peopleRepository.All()
                            .Where(p => p.id == candidate.id);
            successful = successful.Union(successfulCandidate);
        }
    }

    return successful;
}
```

Is there a limit to the number of times I can union `IQueryables` and still get results using Entity Framework and SQL Server?

Comment: Huh, no. Why do you think it should ?

Answer (score 0):

The Union method uses the `==` operator implementation of the first parameter (here, `successful`). From MSDN :

```
The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that 
represents calling Union<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>) depends
on the implementation of the type of the source1 parameter. The expected behavior is that 
the set union of the elements in source1 and source2 is returned.
```

So if the source is a custom object, you may have an error depending on your implementation of `==` and what you put in your `Union` parameters, but it has nothing to do with the number of calls to `Union`

Comment: OK, but throw in EF and SQL Server, is there a limit to the number of calls that it can handle?

Comment: I don't see how that could make any difference. Using `Union` on an entity is the same thing (for EF) as modifying it's collection by hand

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to think it could cause a problem ?

Comment: I am wondering whether SQL Server, can do an arbitrary number of unions.

Comment: If your question is more toward SQL Server, maybe you should head to [Server Fault](http://serverault.com) ?

Comment: By using EF, your unions will be done on your local context, then saved all at once with the `SaveChanges` method. Therefore SQL Server cannot be a problem here. (I am not sure if EF really handles it like this, don't take this as the truth)